# How to both read and write a file in Lua?

Tags: lua

I would like to know if it is possible to open a file for both reading and writing.

```
f = assert(io.open("words", "r"))
t = f:read("a")
t = string.gsub(t, "Bad", "Good")
f = assert(io.open("words", "w"))
f:write(t)
f:close()
```

The above code seems to be working as expected. Sometimes what seems to work is not valid. For example, in some Unix pipelines, data is swallowed by one of the commands in an unintended fashion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Either close the old `f` before you open the new one, or open it with mode `r+` instead of `r` and `seek` back to the beginning before you write it back out.

Comment: In my opinion, it is necessary to specify that `io.open` is approximately derived from (or mimics) the C function `fopen`. The Lua reference manual doesn't really specify what the "[update](http://www.lua.org/manual/5.4/manual.html#pdf-io.open)" mode is. The C standard requires that a "read or write operation is not performed one after the other directly or immediately" ([e.g. POSIX](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/fopen.html)).

Comment: I find that a little difficult to understand. Maybe the user need to know the C language?

Comment: ```f = assert(io.open("words", "r+"))

t = f:read("a")
t = string.gsub(t, "Bad", "Good")

f:seek("set")

f:write(t)

f:close()```